# Bullet - RigidBody Initial Rotation/Translation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, bullet

I've been looking online for a good amount of time and can't seem to find the solution to my problem. The problem is that I can't find a way to set the initial rotation and translation for a RigidBody when the scene starts. Could someone tell me where I can find the answer, or show me? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can guess, there are a lot of documents about this in the internet, but  they often lack documents or misleading.

Here is the set-transformation function (I tested):-

```
// `body` is `btRigidBody*` 
btTransform transform = body -> getCenterOfMassTransform();
transform.setOrigin(new_position);               //set position
//transform.setBasis(const btMatrix3x3& basis)   //set orientation
body -> setCenterOfMassTransform(transform);
```

Recommend reading: http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtTransform.html

Comment: Thanks, this will help me get into bullet with more ease.